# TCSH Shell Script: substitute a variable using sed inside file

Tags: variables, sed, tcsh, eol

in my tcsh script I have this

```
sed -i "s/^${y}$//g" $x
```

How do I get this to work? either I get no change or some error like Illegal Variable Name or Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters. Tried different combinations of "". '' within the sed . Example

```
sed 's/^'"${y}"'$//g' $x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion of variable names in double-quoted strings is tricky in tcsh. In your command:

```
sed -i "s/^${y}$//g" $x
```

the value of the shell or environment variable `$y` should be expanded correctly, but the shell will try to expand `$/` to the value of `$/`, which as the error message says is an illegal variable name.

Your second command:

```
sed 's/^'"${y}"'$//g' $x
```

is *almost* correct; it's just missing the `-i` argument to `sed`.

This should work:
.
    sed 's/^'"${y}"'$//g' $x

The `{` and `}` around `y` aren't needed in this case, so you could write:

```
sed 's/^'"${y}"'$//g' $x
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
sed -i "s/^$y"'$'"//g" $x
```

This last version switches from double quotes to single quotes, and back to double, *just* around the `$` character.  It's a matter of emphasis, whether you want to use single quotes only around the `$` that you don't want expanded, or to use double quotes only around `$y` which you do want expanded.

Even more simply, you can escape a `$` character in a double-quoted string by preceding it with `\` (I think that may be specific to tcsh; the original csh might not have been able to do that). So I think this is the preferred approach -- assuming you have tcsh and not old-style csh:

```
sed -i "s/^$y\$//g" $x
```

I'm assuming that what you want to do is update the file named by `$x` in place, deleting the string contained in `$y` at the beginning of each line. That seems to be what you're trying to do, but I can't be certain.